# select max value from oracle table in c#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, max

I have an OracleCommand to select maximum value of type NUMBER from oracle table in a C# application using OracleConnection. when code is excuted I get the value with M letter at the end! so if we suppose max value is 2544, then I get 2544M as maximum value.

here is the code:

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT GREATEST(TA_Counts) FROM Test3.Trn_Sfd", Con2);
Con2.Open();
var returvalue = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

why value is not return as 2544 int value?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the value is a `decimal`. This happens due to the type of your column in table. You could verify this looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk72thhd(v=vs.110).aspx) table. If your data type is either integer or float the .net type returned by the reader is `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Greatest doesn't give you the max value of your table:

```
SQL> with t as (
  2    select 1 id, 2 value from dual union all
  3    select 2 id, 4 value from dual
  4  )
  5  select GREATEST(id)  
  6    from t
  7  /

GREATEST(ID)
------------
           1
           2
```

The `GREATEST` function gives you the max value among several values, like:

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (
  2    select 1 id, 2 value from dual union all
  3    select 2 id, 4 value from dual
  4  )
  5  select GREATEST(id, value)
  6*   from t
SQL> /

GREATEST(ID,VALUE)
------------------
                 2
                 4
```

You have to use the max function:

```
SQL> ED
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (
  2    select 1 id, 2 value from dual union all
  3    select 2 id, 4 value from dual
  4  )
  5  select max(id)
  6*   from t
SQL> /

   MAX(ID)
----------
         2
```

you might need to use implicit conversion:

```
(int)command.ExecuteScalar()
```

use the type you need